# Stubbing a read only property with Rhino Mock

Tags: c#-4.0, rhino-mocks

I have a class with a private set property that I want to stub out with rhino mocks.
 When I try to do this, though, it gives me a run time error. I'm new to using Rhino Mocks so I must be missing something here...

```
public interface IView
{
    bool isDialog { get; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void SomeTest()
{
   var m_MockRepository = new MockRepository();

   Helper.SetDialog(m_MockRepository,false);

    //Asserts and such
}

static class Helper
{

    internal static SetDialog(MockRepository mockRepository, bool isDialog)

    var viewStub=mockRepository.stub<IView>();
    viewStub.Stub(x=>x.isDialog).Return(isDialog);
}
```

The gives me a  stack trace when executes line `viewStub.Stub(x=>x.isDialog).Return(isDialog)`

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're mixing different syntax of Rhino Mocks: Record-Replay and AAA (Arrange, Act, Assert), and the Mock is in invalid state.
It should work (based on my small test), if instead of using the `MockRepository` object, you would use the following:

```
var viewStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IView>();
```